# Wrap Eigen's tensor class to create dynamic rank tensors?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

Eigen's tensor module supports static rank tensors through the use of template arguments, with something like `Eigen::Tensor<typename T,int dims>`. I'm only going to be using `Eigen::Tensor<double, n>`, where n isn't necessarily known at compile time. Is there anyway to make a class like:

```
class TensorWrapper{
    Eigen::Tensor<double,??????> t; //not sure what could go here
    TensorWrapper(int dimensions){
        t = Eigen::Tensor<double,dimensions>(); //wouldn't work either way
    }
};
```

I know that `Eigen::Tensor<double,2>` and `Eigen::Tensor<double,3>` have absolutely nothing to do with each other because they are templated, and that I can't have template arguments determined at run-time, so the above would fail in every possible way. I also know that tensors in Tensorflow support this, but they don't have tensor contraction in c++ (which is why I need tensors in the first place). Is there any way to do what I wanted to above, even for a limited number of dimensions (I won't need more than 5 or 6)? If not, are there any tensor libraries for c++ that support dynamic rank and tensor contraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I wrote this multidimensional tensor library (its not full fledged) it supports basic operations like dotproduct and pointwise elements.

https://github.com/josephjaspers/BlackCat_Tensors

```
Tensor<float> tensor3 = {3, 4, 5};   -- generates a 3 dimensional tensor (3 rows, 4 columns, 5 pages)
Tensor<float> tensor5 = {1,2,3,4,5}; -- generate a 5d tensors (1 rows, 2 columns, 3 pages, etc)
tensor3[1] = 3;                      -- returns the second matrix and sets all the values to 3. 
tensor3[1][2];                       -- returns the second matrx and then then 3rd column of that matrix
tensor3({1,2,3},{2,2});              -- at index 1,2,3, returns a sub-matrix of dimensions 2x2
```

All of the accessor operators [] (int index) and ({initializer_list index},{initializer_list shape}) return seperate tensors but they all refer to the same internal array. Therefor you can modify the original tensor from these sub_tensors.

All the data is allocated on a single array. If you want to use dotproduct you need to link it to BLAS. Here's the header file, it details most of the methods. https://github.com/josephjaspers/BlackCat_Tensors/blob/master/BC_Headers/Tensor.h

However, it is not particularly fast, personally I use this personal library just for prototyping NeuralNetworks (https://github.com/josephjaspers/BlackCat_NeuralNetworks).

Comment: Neural networks were actually the exact reason I needed tensors. I'll take a look at it, thanks. I might want a slightly more optimized library though. Can yours use the gpu?

Comment: I can re-add the Gpu lib to my github when I get back, Though, it’s not as fully fledged as the CPU.

Comment: I added the GPU lib again, you will have to compile it with CUDA. 
Only floats are supported. You will have to tinker with the thread/block count (as its hardware specific)

Relevant files

This is the calling class: 
https://github.com/josephjaspers/BlackCat_Tensors/blob/master/BC_LAR_GPU_impl/GPU_caller.cu

This is the method list (should be the same as the CPU)
https://github.com/josephjaspers/BlackCat_Tensors/blob/master/BC_Headers/BLACKCAT_GPU_MATHEMATICS.cuh

The folder with all the implementations:
https://github.com/josephjaspers/BlackCat_Tensors/tree/master/BC_LAR_GPU_impl

Comment: Some notes:

1. Needs compiled with NVCC
2. Needs to be linked to cublas
3. You can modify the math_library implementations in the folder I linked above.
4. The block/threads is machine specific and you may need to tinker with them. (you can modify them in the implementations folder-  GPU_caller.cu file.)

Comment: I'm definitely not advanced enough to try anything with the gpu stuff, lol. I've never even used CUDA before. I'm thinking about just writing my own tensor class to see how they work. I'll probably end up using yours with only the cpu though. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456458/implementation-of-multi-dimensional-array-with-an-array-or-vector/47128991#47128991

In the bottom of this question I wrote some code explaining how to create the recursive indexing pattern (in case you want to right your own multi-dimensional tensor library)